# Using a style resource from one project in another project

Tags: wpf

In one project, I have a resource dictioary and a usercontrol. A style is defined in the resource dictionary and the usercontrol uses the style in resource dictionary via staticresource. When another project tries to use this usercontrol, we get an exception 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Is there any way we can solve this?

Comment: Have you set this resource dictionary called Generic in the Themes folder of your user control project.  If you do this then it should auto load the styles

Comment: Can you post XAML from the other project, to show us how you are trying to use that style, please?

Comment: If you remove the resource from the usercontrol, does it work?

Comment: @BobVale Yes, the themestyles folder has this resource dictionary. But, for some projects it is not giving any exception and for other projects it is giving this exception.

Comment: @sthotakura below is the code which i am using in a new project where it's giving me exception.   `<Grid>
        <controls:AutoCompleteTextBox x:Name="AutoCompleteTextBox"/>
    </Grid>` I am not using any other resources to refer any styles of this control.

Comment: @Daniel It is working fine if i remove the style from userControl.

Comment: Hi, Can you post more information on exception as well, please?

Comment: @sthotakura XamlParseException occurred : 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '26' and line position '32'.

Comment: Did you check the innerexception details of that exception?

Comment: @sthotakura this is the innerexception - {"Cannot find resource named 'ListBoxItemStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive."}

Comment: @user2915926 where is ListBoxItemStyle defined?

Comment: @BobVale Sorry for the late reply.. ListBoxItemStyle is defined in the ResourceDictionary.